# How to retrieve the method parameters of a mock-injected method, which is called by the function being tested?

Tags: java, mockito, junit4

```
public class SearchServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    SearchService searchService;

    @Mock
    Mapvalues mapvalues;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashmap<>();
        File fp = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:test.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fp);
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            map.put(line, 300);
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething()
    {
       searchService.doSomething();
       //so basically this doSomething() method calls the method mapvalues.getval(String key), 
       //but instead I want to perform map.get(key) when the method is called.
    }
}
```

So the doSomething() method calls the mapvalues.getval(String key) method, which returns an integer value, but I want to pass the key value to map.get(key) when the method is called. How do I retrieve that parameter?

Comment: In case it is at all possible to use it, I will note that this kind of advanced mock interaction is one of the cases that the Spock Framework makes much cleaner to work with. Spock is a domain-specific language written in Groovy that runs on top of JUnit specifically to make writing JUnit tests easier and simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing `searchService.doSomething();`
I will assume that the body of this method contains the statement `mapvalues.getval("KEY-VALUE");`

Before doing the test call, in your setup, stub the method that you expect to be invoked

```
    when(mapvalues.getval(any())).then(new Answer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            return map.get(invocation.getArgument(0, String.class));
        }
    });
```

After the test call, you want to make sure the wanted method has been invoked with the expected parameter values.

```
   verify(mapvalues).getval(eq("KEY-VALUE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when(mapvalues.get(any())).thenAnswer((Answer<String>) invocation -> {
    String key = invocation.getArgument(0);
});
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to answer more thoroughly.